# jQuery passing json array with ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I have ajax request to process array (I trimmed the script in order to concentrate on the right part)

My ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {
           'usertrips': JSON.stringify(usertrips)
           },
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(response){  
            $('#alerts').html('<div class="success">OK</div>');
          },
        error: function(){ 
            $('#alerts').html('<div class="error">NOT OK</div>');
        }
    });
```

disputed part of code in test.php (accesing the array)

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['usertrips']);
    foreach($data as $item){
    echo $item;
    /// insert each item to mysql
}
```

So there is something weird happening. Script is working in general till the moment I insert disputed code. When I check in console array is returned, no errors. jQuery moves to error section of the code.

Any advice? What do i do wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You've told jQuery to expect a JSON response via `dataType: 'json'`. Using `echo $item` in your `foreach` loop almost guarantees that your response will not be JSON. jQuery provides information in the `error` callback. Why don't you use it, ie `error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }`

Comment: yes you are right ...used  $response['usertrips'] .= "$item<br>"; thanks to pointing this out to me.

Comment: btw why downvote, it's a learning process sometimes we just do not see things, or do not understand them correctly. I spent enough time working this out, and Phil in no time put me on the right track.

Comment: Are you saying your problem is solved? Do you know why you used `dataType: 'json'`? If not, then the first thing you should do is look at the documentation for the code you are using, especially if you don't know *why* you are using it

Comment: i was expecting json_decode to do the job. obviously didn't work, i posted answer with the working code. Thanks Phil.

Comment: But `json_decode` has nothing to do with the response. Your jQuery code literally has `dataType: 'json'`. **Do you know what that does?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156237/discussion-between-nita-and-phil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {
       'usertrips': JSON.stringify(usertrips)
       },
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(response){  
        $('#alerts').html('<div class="success">OK</div>');
        $("#results").html(response.usertrips);
      },
    error: function(){ 
        $('#alerts').html('<div class="error">NOT OK</div>');
    }
});
```

php:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['usertrips']);
    foreach($data as $item){
    $response['usertrips'] .= "<li>$item<li>";
    /// insert each item to mysql
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$strRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');
$Request = json_decode($strRequest);
```

Comment: OP is posting a JSON string for the "usertrips" property in an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request payload. `php://input` will **not** be a JSON string